# ng-model converting dictionary to string

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a combobox whose options correspond to an array of dictionaries:

```
<select class="form-control" id="role_list" ng-model="dialogdata.role" multiple>
    <option ng-repeat="role in roles" value="{{role}}">{{role.name}}</option>
</select>
```

And here is the array it uses to generate the list of combobox options:

```
$scope.roles = [ {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'ROLE_USER'
}, {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'ROLE_ADMIN'
}, {
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'ROLE_TPB_REPORT_USER'
}, {
    'id': 4,
    'name': 'ROLE_TPB_REPORT_ADMIN'
}];
```

It displays the options correctly in the combobox, and lets me select them, however when that data then gets processed inside a method I set a variable to the value of selected options:

```
var newtype = dialogdata.type;
```

For this test, I select the first two options, then submit it. When it gets into the method where the var is set, the dictionary entries have been converted into strings. In the console, if I set a breakpoint I can see var newtype getting set to this:

```
["{"id":1, "name":"ROLE_USER"}", "{"id":2, "name":"ROLE_ADMIN"}"]
```

I need the value to be an array of actual dictionaries not the string version of them, is this just a limitation of ng-model, or can I finagle this into working? Is there another, better option that will preserve the type?

Comment: Try to change value binding                                                                       
 <select class="form-control" id="role_list" ng-model="dialogdata.role" multiple>
    <option ng-repeat="role in roles" value="{{role.id}}">{{role.name}}</option>
</select>

Comment: @AhammadaliPK That looks like what I have now...did you mean to paste something else in, or am I reading that wrong?

Comment: I just changed value = {{role.id}} , just to double check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** 
Based upon our chat, use your original code and:

**Change**

```
var newtype = dialogdata.type;
```

**To**

```
var newtype = JSON.parse(dialogdata.type);
console.log(newtype); // should provide your javascript object (dictionary)
```

You are passing the entire dictionary to the `value` attribute of each `<option>` element. Traditionally, we place this `id` in the value attribute and the `name` (in this case) as the text description.

Comment: when I do that, I end up with ["1", "2"], when what I need to pass is both dictionaries...I could do some parsing to assemble the dictionaries or grab them from the index or something, I was just wondering if there was a way to do it with something like ng-value

Comment: HTML doesn't know anything about data types other than text. Any value in an `HTMLInputElement` will be text. It sounds as if you simply need to use your first go and parse it back into a javascript object. Let me update my answer based upon this convo.

Comment: Casbum Thanks for the help, I went ahead and did the mapping by ID and then assembled the array using those. It works!